# load a slick-slide-carousel with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to load a slick-slide-carousel with ajax so that when one of the radiobuttons is pressed, the new images are loaded via ajax.
But I have a problem because when loading the new images, all the images of the carousel are displayed one on top of the other for a second.
It can be seen on this page: http://infrangible-discoun.000webhostapp.com/slideAjax/, by pressing any of the radio-buttons.This is the code.

index.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="jsSlick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsSlick/slick/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsSlick/slick/slick-theme.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" charset="UTF-8">      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosSlick.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
        <script src="ajaxIdProducto.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div id='foto'>
            <div class='contenedor2 slideshow2'>
                <img src="imagenes/1.jpg">
                <img src="imagenes/2.jpg">
                <img src="imagenes/3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div>
        <form id="formOpciones" action="#" method="post"> 
            <label for='color'>Elegir</label>
            <input type="radio" class="color" name="color" value="blanco">
            <input type="radio" class="color" name="color" value="negro">
            <input type="radio" class="color" name="color" value="gris"> 
            <input type="radio" class="color" name="color" value="azul"> 
        </form>
        </div>    
    </body>
    <script src="slick2.js"></script>
</html>
```

ajaxIdProducto.js:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){              
    $(document).on("change",'.color', function(event) {     
    var $form = $("#formOpciones");    
    var url1 = "obtenerFoto.php";
    {       
       $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url1,                     
           data: $form.serialize(), 
           success: function(data)             
           {              
             $('#foto').html(data);           
           }
       });  
    }    
});   
});
```

obtenerFoto.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Obtener Foto</title>
        <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="jsSlick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsSlick/slick/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jsSlick/slick/slick-theme.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" charset="UTF-8">      
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilosSlick.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>">
        <script src="ajaxIdProducto.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function slickCarousel() {
                $('.slideshow2').slick({
                    dots:true,
                    arrows: true,
                    fade:false,
                    autoplay:false,        
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    
                });
              }
              function destroyCarousel() {
                if ($('.slideshow2').hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                  $('.slideshow2').slick('destroy');
                }      
              }            
                destroyCarousel();
                slickCarousel();
        </script>
        <?php
        echo("<div class='contenedor2 slideshow2'>");
        echo("<img src='imagenes/11.jpg'>");
        echo("<img src='imagenes/12.jpg'>");
        echo("<img src='imagenes/13.jpg'>");
        echo("</div>");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

slick2.js:

```
$(".slideshow2").slick({
    dots:true,
    arrows: true,
    fade:false,
    autoplay:false,        
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1, 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because when you call ajax obtenerFoto.php some of the scripts reload. After the script has finished loading, the slide carousel changes.

[ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okyyE.png)

Maybe you can try by changing the file obtenerFoto.php like this:

```
<?php
    echo("<div class='contenedor2 slideshow2'>");
    echo("<img src='imagenes/11.jpg'>");
    echo("<img src='imagenes/12.jpg'>");
    echo("<img src='imagenes/13.jpg'>");
    echo("</div>");
?>
```